# Is there a way to implement drag and drop in a grid, using react beautiful dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

this is my first question here. As the title says, i'd like to know if is there a way to create a dnd grid using react beautiful-dnd library. I've already found out that the library supports vertical and horizontal dnd, and i've already tried both, but what about if i mix the 2 things? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to implement dnd which support vertical and horizontal move right ?